# Что такое config.h.in?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Мой c++ уровень около нуля.

Клонировал с github проект. Пытаюсь собрать. Получил ошибку

> E1696 не удается открыть источник файл "config.h"

В папке с исходниками, есть файл config.h.in

Достаточно просто его переименовать? Что-то это ".in" значит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это шаблон, на основании которого кодогенерирующие утилиты конфигурирования создают заголовочный файл, который затем включается в исходники программы. Распространен по большей часть в проектах autotools, где его обработка происходит при выполнении `configure`. Но может присутствовать в качестве атавизма и в других инструментах, как вышеупомянутом cmake.

Comment: Как понять какой у меня случай? https://github.com/openldap/openldap/tree/master/contrib/ldapc%2B%2B

Comment: @4per Это проект autotools, там есть configure, Makefile.am, aclocal.m4 и т.п.

Comment: т.е. так просто в Visual Studio на винде не запустить?

Comment: @4per Ну можете самостоятельно создать проект Visual Studio на основе этого кода...

Comment: Ну я и пробую... для начала просто переименую в config.h ..

Answer (score 2):

Это файл для генерации заголовочного файла после подстановки var'ов в CMake
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html

Работает это так :

1) Вы создаете *.n.in файл и указываете туда переменные из CMake конфигурации (к примреру версия или что-то другое)

2) Далее во время генерации CMake проекта *.h.in подставляет значение переменных

3) создается новый .h файл с данными которые взялись из конфигурации CMake

Comment: Скорей всего это не cmake, а autotools...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну нету названия проекта ))) я и выбрал смейк